# Learning Audio Manipulation

Tags: windows, audio, theory, audio-recording

I want to learn how applications like CakeWalk, Cubase, and ProTools are built. Are there any good resources out there to learn this type of development?

**Resources**

- [Digital Signal Processing Basics](http://www.dsptutor.freeuk.com/)

Comment: Wow. Good question. Once again, I hate you for figuring out good questions to ask.

Comment: Don't hate the playa hate the game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn about how the capabilities of these programs are implemented (I'm talking about filtering, synthesis, mixing, etc.), read as much as you can about **digital signal processing** (DSP). If you happen to be in a position to take a DSP class at a college or university, you'd probably get a lot of good information out of that. (I've taken a couple such classes myself and they were fantastic) Beyond that, there are dozens of books and research papers out there concerning various aspects of DSP; just try to find a good one (or several) and dive in. A Google search can definitely get you started.

If you want to know more about audio programming in general, i.e. how to access the operating system's audio resources (microphone/speakers/etc.), I guess I could echo Dan's suggestion of looking at Audacity...

Answer (score 2):

The [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) folks might be able to help.  Getting involved with an open source project is a great way to help the community and get mentored on a new technology.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in this topic and learning more about Digital Music Technology could also look into https://ardour.org/ - an open source Digital Audio Workstation in ongoing development and with an active developer community. http://community.ardour.org/community.

*"Ardour is an open source, collaborative effort of a worldwide team including musicians, programmers, and professional recording engineers. Development is transparent — anyone can watch our work as it happens. Like a good piece of vintage hardware, you can open the box and look inside. "*